# Autofac Lifetime Scope with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, autofac, ioc-container

I'm new to Autofac.
I'm trying to integrate autofac with asp.net mvc application with the full solution following Repository pattern

Following are the configuration that I did.

> MvcProject.Website.Global.asax.cs

```
..Application_start() {
  App_Start.AutofacConfig.ConfigureContainer();
}
```

> MvcProject.Website.App_Start.AutofacConfig.cs

NOTE: I have registered RegisterTypes as Modules in different projects and bind them from following main config file.

```
public static class AutofacConfig
   {
       public static void ConfigureContainer()
       {
           var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
  builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly).PropertiesAutowired();

           //Register Repository dependencies
           builder.RegisterModule(new RepositoryModule("mssql"));

           //Register Application dependencies
           builder.RegisterModule(new ApplicationModule());

           var container = builder.Build();
           DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
       }
   }
```

Then, in Application layer, Type registration done by extending Module abstract class

> MvcProject.Application.ApplicationModule.cs

```
public class ApplicationModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(Containerbuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<MyService>.InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        base.Load(builder);
    }
}
```

Then, from the controller

> MvcProject.Website.Controllers.MyController.cs

```
public class MyController : Controller
   {
       private ILifetimeScope _scope;

       public MyController(ILifetimeScope scope)
       {
           _scope = scope;
       }

       public ActionResult SayHello()
       {
           using (var localscope = _scope.BeginLifetimeScope())
           {
               var service = localscope.Resolve<MyService>();
               var viewModel = service.GetMyViewModel();
               return View(viewModel);
           }
       }
   }
```

My main questions are:

1. to avoid Memory leak issues, do we need to define lifetime scopes (as in the above MyController's SayHello action) in MVC Controllers or is that NOT necessary for the MVC ?
2. Delegating the Type Registry to individual projects using Module is the correct way or is there a better/correct way ?
3. Is there a better way to get ILifetimeScope inside the MyController without passing "ILifetimeScope" parameter from Constructor of the Controller ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you've already checked out the Autofac docs for some examples and explanations of things like [how to integrate with MVC](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html) and [how lifetime scopes work](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetime/working-with-scopes.html) so I'll keep it short:

- **Don't create your own lifetime scopes in controllers if you don't have to.** Each request already gets its own lifetime scope - everything you resolve that's scoped to a request or on a per-instance basis will get disposed for you at the end of the request.
- **How you register your types and keep them organized is highly subjective based on how your app is structured.** Modules on a per project basis is one way (a good way) to do it.
- **Generally avoid passing an `ILifetimeScope` around in your controllers.** Just take your dependencies in the constructor for the controller like any other inversion-of-control/dependency injection scenario. If you want to defer resolving a service (like you may not need it) then [look at things like the `Func<T>` relationship that Autofac supports](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html).

Comment: Thank you for the detail reply.

Comment: Thank you for the detail reply. I read through the following article and it was metion to use lifetimescope to avoide memory leaks. http://nblumhardt.com/2011/01/an-autofac-lifetime-primer/   . So, i think it is not applicable to web requests ??

Comment: You do want to use lifetime scopes. It is applicable to MVC. It's just that with the integration Autofac provides, that's taken care of for you.